# How to load deep learning model in jni

Tags: deep-learning, java-native-interface, caffe, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

https://github.com/huaweicodelabs/HiAI-Foundation
I have a question about the above site.
Preparation && Getting Started,

```
5.Before using a model, you need to load the model.
   The DDK supports both single-model and multi-model loading.
   In sync mode, the app layer loads the model by calling the loadModelSync function at the JNI layer.
   In async mode, the app layer loads the model by calling the loadModelAsync function at the JNI layer.
```

Here, it says to load the model in JNI, but I'm not sure.
If it was keras in python

```
model = load_model ('squeezenet_v1.0.caffemodel')
```

I think I will write.
Assuming that you use squeezenet_v1.0.caffemodel, please tell me how to write it.

classify_sync_jni.cpp

```
/**
 * @file classify_jni.cpp
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2019. Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */

#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory.h>
#include "HiAiModelManagerService.h"
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

#define LOG_TAG "SYNC_DDK_MSG"
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
// 如果expr为true，则执行exec_expr，不打印日志
#define IF_BOOL_EXEC(expr, exec_expr) \
    { \
        if (expr) { \
            exec_expr; \
        } \
    }

using namespace std;
using namespace hiai;

static shared_ptr<AiModelMngerClient> g_clientSync = nullptr;
static vector<vector<TensorDimension>> inputDimension;
static vector<vector<TensorDimension>> outputDimension;
static vector<vector<shared_ptr<AiTensor>>> input_tensor;
static vector<vector<shared_ptr<AiTensor>>> output_tensor;

static map<string, int> g_syncNameToIndex;
static long time_use_sync = 0;

static const int SUCCESS = 0;
static const int FAILED = -1;

void ResourceDestroy(shared_ptr<AiModelBuilder>& modelBuilder, vector<MemBuffer*>& memBuffers)
{
    if (modelBuilder == nullptr) {
        LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] modelBuilder is null.");
        return;
    }

    for (auto tmpBuffer : memBuffers) {
        modelBuilder->MemBufferDestroy(tmpBuffer);
    }
    return;
}

int LoadSync(vector<string>& names, vector<string>& modelPaths, shared_ptr<AiModelMngerClient>& client)
{
    int ret;
    vector<shared_ptr<AiModelDescription>> modelDescs;
    vector<MemBuffer*> memBuffers;
    shared_ptr<AiModelBuilder> modelBuilder = make_shared<AiModelBuilder>(client);
    if (modelBuilder == nullptr) {
        LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] creat modelBuilder failed.");
        return FAILED;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < modelPaths.size(); ++i) {
        string modelPath = modelPaths[i];
        string modelName = names[i];
        g_syncNameToIndex[modelName] = i;

        // We can achieve the optimization by loading model from OM file.
        LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] modelpath is %s\n.", modelPath.c_str());
        MemBuffer* buffer = modelBuilder->InputMemBufferCreate(modelPath);
        if (buffer == nullptr) {
            LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] cannot find the model file.");
            return FAILED;
        }
        memBuffers.push_back(buffer);

        string modelNameFull = string(modelName) + string(".om");
        shared_ptr<AiModelDescription> desc =
            make_shared<AiModelDescription>(modelNameFull, AiModelDescription_Frequency_HIGH, HIAI_FRAMEWORK_NONE,
                HIAI_MODELTYPE_ONLINE, AiModelDescription_DeviceType_NPU);
        if (desc == nullptr) {
            LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] LoadModelSync: desc make_shared error.");
            ResourceDestroy(modelBuilder, memBuffers);
            return FAILED;
        }
        desc->SetModelBuffer(buffer->GetMemBufferData(), buffer->GetMemBufferSize());

        LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] loadModel %s IO Tensor.", desc->GetName().c_str());
        modelDescs.push_back(desc);
    }

    ret = client->Load(modelDescs);
    ResourceDestroy(modelBuilder, memBuffers);
    if (ret != 0) {
        LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] Model Load Failed.");
        return FAILED;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

int UpdateSyncInputTensorVec(vector<TensorDimension>& inputDims, bool isUseAipp, string& modelName)
{
    input_tensor.clear();
    vector<shared_ptr<AiTensor>> inputTensors;
    int ret = FAILED;
    for (auto inDim : inputDims) {
        shared_ptr<AiTensor> input = make_shared<AiTensor>();
        if (isUseAipp) {
            ret = input->Init(inDim.GetNumber(), inDim.GetHeight(), inDim.GetWidth(), AiTensorImage_YUV420SP_U8);
            LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] model %s uses AIPP(input).", modelName.c_str());
        } else {
            ret = input->Init(&inDim);
            LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] model %s does not use AIPP(input).", modelName.c_str());
        }
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(ret != SUCCESS, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] model %s AiTensor Init failed(input).", modelName.c_str());
                     return FAILED);
        inputTensors.push_back(input);
    }
    input_tensor.push_back(inputTensors);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(input_tensor.size() == 0, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] input_tensor.size() == 0"); return FAILED);

    return SUCCESS;
}

int UpdateSyncOutputTensorVec(vector<TensorDimension>& outputDims, string& modelName)
{
    output_tensor.clear();
    vector<shared_ptr<AiTensor>> outputTensors;
    int ret = FAILED;
    for (auto outDim : outputDims) {
        shared_ptr<AiTensor> output = make_shared<AiTensor>();
        ret = output->Init(&outDim);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(ret != SUCCESS, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] model %s AiTensor Init failed(output).", modelName.c_str());
                     return FAILED);
        outputTensors.push_back(output);
    }
    output_tensor.push_back(outputTensors);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(output_tensor.size() == 0, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] output_tensor.size() == 0"); return FAILED);

    return SUCCESS;
}

shared_ptr<AiModelMngerClient> LoadModelSync(vector<string> names, vector<string> modelPaths, vector<bool> Aipps)
{
    shared_ptr<AiModelMngerClient> clientSync = make_shared<AiModelMngerClient>();
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(clientSync == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] Model Manager Client make_shared error.");
                 return nullptr);
    int ret = clientSync->Init(nullptr);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(ret != SUCCESS, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] Model Manager Init Failed."); return nullptr);
    ret = LoadSync(names, modelPaths, clientSync);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(ret != SUCCESS, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_ASYNC] LoadSync Failed."); return nullptr);

    inputDimension.clear();
    outputDimension.clear();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i) {
        string modelName = names[i];
        bool isUseAipp = Aipps[i];
        LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] Get model %s IO Tensor. Use AIPP %d", modelName.c_str(), isUseAipp);
        vector<TensorDimension> inputDims, outputDims;
        ret = clientSync->GetModelIOTensorDim(string(modelName) + string(".om"), inputDims, outputDims);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(ret != SUCCESS, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] Get Model IO Tensor Dimension failed,ret is %d.", ret);
                     return nullptr);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(inputDims.size() == 0, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] inputDims.size() == 0"); return nullptr);
        inputDimension.push_back(inputDims);
        outputDimension.push_back(outputDims);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(UpdateSyncInputTensorVec(inputDims, isUseAipp, modelName) != SUCCESS, return nullptr);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(UpdateSyncOutputTensorVec(outputDims, modelName) != SUCCESS, return nullptr);
    }
    return clientSync;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_huawei_hiaidemo_utils_ModelManager_GetTimeUseSync(JNIEnv* env, jclass type)
{
    return time_use_sync;
}

int setField(JNIEnv* env, int len, jobject& modelInfo, jmethodID listGet)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        jobject modelInfoObj = env->CallObjectMethod(modelInfo, listGet, i);
        jclass modelInfoClass = env->GetObjectClass(modelInfoObj);
        jfieldID inputIdN = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "input_N", "I");
        jfieldID inputIdC = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "input_C", "I");
        jfieldID inputIdH = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "input_H", "I");
        jfieldID inputIdW = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "input_W", "I");
        jfieldID inputNumber = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "input_Number", "I");
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, inputIdN, inputDimension[i][0].GetNumber());
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, inputIdC, inputDimension[i][0].GetChannel());
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, inputIdH, inputDimension[i][0].GetHeight());
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, inputIdW, inputDimension[i][0].GetWidth());
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, inputNumber, inputDimension[i].size());

        jfieldID outputIdN = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "output_N", "I");
        jfieldID outputIdC = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "output_C", "I");
        jfieldID outputIdH = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "output_H", "I");
        jfieldID outputIdW = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "output_W", "I");
        jfieldID outputNumber = env->GetFieldID(modelInfoClass, "output_Number", "I");
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, outputIdN, outputDimension[i][0].GetNumber());
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, outputIdC, outputDimension[i][0].GetChannel());
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, outputIdH, outputDimension[i][0].GetHeight());
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, outputIdW, outputDimension[i][0].GetWidth());
        env->SetIntField(modelInfoObj, outputNumber, outputDimension[i].size());
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_huawei_hiaidemo_utils_ModelManager_loadModelSync(
    JNIEnv* env, jclass type, jobject modelInfo)
{
    jclass classList = env->GetObjectClass(modelInfo);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(classList == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find List class."); return nullptr);
    jmethodID listGet = env->GetMethodID(classList, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jmethodID listSize = env->GetMethodID(classList, "size", "()I");
    int len = static_cast<int>(env->CallIntMethod(modelInfo, listSize));
    vector<string> names, modelPaths;
    vector<bool> aipps;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        jobject modelInfoObj = env->CallObjectMethod(modelInfo, listGet, i);
        jclass modelInfoClass = env->GetObjectClass(modelInfoObj);
        jmethodID getOfflineModelName = env->GetMethodID(modelInfoClass, "getOfflineModelName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
        jmethodID getModelPath = env->GetMethodID(modelInfoClass, "getModelPath", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
        jmethodID getUseAIPP = env->GetMethodID(modelInfoClass, "getUseAIPP", "()Z");
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(getOfflineModelName == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find getOfflineModelName method.");
                     return nullptr);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(getModelPath == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find getModelPath method.");
                     return nullptr);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(getUseAIPP == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find getUseAIPP method."); return nullptr);

        jboolean useaipp = (jboolean)env->CallBooleanMethod(modelInfoObj, getUseAIPP);
        jstring modelname = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(modelInfoObj, getOfflineModelName);
        jstring modelpath = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(modelInfoObj, getModelPath);
        const char* modelName = env->GetStringUTFChars(modelname, 0);
        LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] modelName is %s .", modelName);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(modelName == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] modelName is invalid."); return nullptr);
        const char* modelPath = env->GetStringUTFChars(modelpath, 0);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(modelPath == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] modelPath is invalid."); return nullptr);
        LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] useaipp is %d.", bool(useaipp == JNI_TRUE));
        aipps.push_back(bool(useaipp == JNI_TRUE));
        names.push_back(string(modelName));
        modelPaths.push_back(string(modelPath));
    }
    // load
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(!g_clientSync, g_clientSync = LoadModelSync(names, modelPaths, aipps); IF_BOOL_EXEC(
        g_clientSync == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] g_clientSync loadModel is nullptr."); return nullptr));
    LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] sync load model INPUT NCHW : %d %d %d %d.", inputDimension[0][0].GetNumber(),
        inputDimension[0][0].GetChannel(), inputDimension[0][0].GetHeight(), inputDimension[0][0].GetWidth());
    LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] sync load model OUTPUT NCHW : %d %d %d %d.", outputDimension[0][0].GetNumber(),
        outputDimension[0][0].GetChannel(), outputDimension[0][0].GetHeight(), outputDimension[0][0].GetWidth());
    setField(env, len, modelInfo, listGet);

    return modelInfo;
}

int runProcess(JNIEnv* env, jobject bufList, jmethodID listGet, int vecIndex, int listLength, const char* modelName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
        jbyteArray buf_ = (jbyteArray)(env->CallObjectMethod(bufList, listGet, i));
        jbyte* dataBuff = nullptr;
        int dataBuffSize = 0;
        dataBuff = env->GetByteArrayElements(buf_, nullptr);
        dataBuffSize = env->GetArrayLength(buf_);
        IF_BOOL_EXEC(input_tensor[vecIndex][i]->GetSize() != dataBuffSize,
                     LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] input->GetSize(%d) != dataBuffSize(%d) ",
                         input_tensor[vecIndex][i]->GetSize(), dataBuffSize);
                     return FAILED);
        memmove(input_tensor[vecIndex][i]->GetBuffer(), dataBuff, (size_t)dataBuffSize);
        env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(buf_, dataBuff, 0);
    }

    AiContext context;
    string key = "model_name";
    string value = modelName;
    value += ".om";
    context.AddPara(key, value);
    LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] runModel modelname:%s", modelName);
    // before process
    struct timeval tpstart, tpend;
    gettimeofday(&tpstart, nullptr);
    int istamp;
    int ret = g_clientSync->Process(context, input_tensor[vecIndex], output_tensor[vecIndex], 1000, istamp);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(ret, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] Runmodel Failed!, ret=%d\n", ret); return FAILED);
    // after process
    gettimeofday(&tpend, nullptr);
    float time_use = 1000000 * (tpend.tv_sec - tpstart.tv_sec) + tpend.tv_usec - tpstart.tv_usec;
    time_use_sync = time_use / 1000;
    LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] inference time %f ms.\n", time_use / 1000);

    return SUCCESS;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_huawei_hiaidemo_utils_ModelManager_runModelSync(
    JNIEnv* env, jclass type, jobject modelInfo, jobject bufList)
{
    // check params
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(env == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] runModelSync env is null"); return nullptr);
    jclass ModelInfo = env->GetObjectClass(modelInfo);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(ModelInfo == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find ModelInfo class."); return nullptr);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(bufList == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] buf_ is null."); return nullptr);
    jmethodID getOfflineModelName = env->GetMethodID(ModelInfo, "getOfflineModelName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jmethodID getModelPath = env->GetMethodID(ModelInfo, "getModelPath", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(getOfflineModelName == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find getOfflineModelName method.");
                 return nullptr);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(getModelPath == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find getModelPath method."); return nullptr);
    jstring modelname = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(modelInfo, getOfflineModelName);
    jstring modelpath = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(modelInfo, getModelPath);
    const char* modelName = env->GetStringUTFChars(modelname, 0);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(modelName == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] modelName is invalid."); return nullptr);
    int vecIndex = g_syncNameToIndex[modelName];
    const char* modelPath = env->GetStringUTFChars(modelpath, 0);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(modelPath == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] modelPath is invalid."); return nullptr);
    // buf_list
    jclass classList = env->GetObjectClass(bufList);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(classList == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find List class."); return nullptr);
    jmethodID listGet = env->GetMethodID(classList, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jmethodID listSize = env->GetMethodID(classList, "size", "()I");
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(listGet == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find get method."); return nullptr);
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(listSize == nullptr, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] can not find size method."); return nullptr);
    int len = static_cast<int>(env->CallIntMethod(bufList, listSize));
    // load
    IF_BOOL_EXEC(!g_clientSync, LOGE("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] Model Manager Client is nullptr."); return nullptr);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(modelpath, modelPath);

    // run
    LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] INPUT NCHW : %d %d %d %d.", inputDimension[0][0].GetNumber(),
        inputDimension[0][0].GetChannel(), inputDimension[0][0].GetHeight(), inputDimension[0][0].GetWidth());
    LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] OUTPUT NCHW : %d %d %d %d.", outputDimension[0][0].GetNumber(),
        outputDimension[0][0].GetChannel(), outputDimension[0][0].GetHeight(), outputDimension[0][0].GetWidth());
    runProcess(env, bufList, listGet, vecIndex, len, modelName);
    // output_tensor
    jclass output_list_class = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
    jmethodID output_list_init = env->GetMethodID(output_list_class, "<init>", "()V");
    jmethodID list_add = env->GetMethodID(output_list_class, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
    jobject output_list = env->NewObject(output_list_class, output_list_init, "");
    long output_tensor_size = output_tensor[vecIndex].size();
    LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] output_tensor_size is %ld .", output_tensor_size);
    for (long j = 0; j < output_tensor_size; j++) {
        float* outputBuffer = (float*)output_tensor[vecIndex][j]->GetBuffer();
        int outputsize = outputDimension[vecIndex][j].GetNumber() * outputDimension[vecIndex][j].GetChannel() *
            outputDimension[vecIndex][j].GetHeight() * outputDimension[vecIndex][j].GetWidth();
        jfloatArray result = env->NewFloatArray(outputsize);
        jfloat temp[outputsize];
        for (int i = 0; i < outputsize; i++) {
            temp[i] = outputBuffer[i];
        }
        env->SetFloatArrayRegion(result, 0, outputsize, temp);
        jboolean output_add = env->CallBooleanMethod(output_list, list_add, result);
        LOGI("[HIAI_DEMO_SYNC] output_add result  is %d .", output_add);
    }
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(modelname, modelName);
    return output_list;
}
```

Comment: squeezenet_v1.0.caffemodel is converted squeezenet_v1.0.h5(keras)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/dev-process-0000001052965551) integration.

Note : Only Huawei phones can be used. Other Huawei phones without the NPU cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks!. Huawei Honor viewpad 6 tablet(Kirin985) is successful to run this demo. To run correctly, Ndk is required version.